platformioでのburn bootloaderエラーについて
Spresense Arduino環境をVSCode+Platformioで使用しています。
早速ですが、Upload時に実行されるflash_writer.pyのpython環境依存性によるエラーは、platformio.ini上にupload_commandとして、pythonスクリプトの代わりにWindows用のexeファイルを指定することで回避することができるのですが、Platformioのburn bootloader機能について、flash_writer.pyによる同じ問題が起きるのですが、その回避方法についてどこにも記載がありません。どなたか、御存じの方がいればご教示ください。
